# Problem does not follow DCP rules in CVXPY

Tags: mathematical-optimization, python-3.7, cvxpy

"Problem does not follow DCP rules" happens at the objective function but mathematically this is convex (I proved) and when I applied the same problem to CVXOPT, it worked.

I don't know what I should modify.

```
x = cp.Variable(data_length)
obj = cp.Minimize((-mu_hat @ x)**2*cp.quad_form(x, covar))

constraints = [sum(x) == 1,  x <= [bounds[i][1] for i in range(len(bounds))], x >= [bounds[i][0] for i in range(len(bounds))]]

prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)

prob.solve()
```

cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules.

Answer (score 2):

Disciplined convex programming does not allow multiplying two convex expressions. You have

```
(-mu_hat @ x)**2
```

and

```
cp.quad_form(x, covar)
```

which are both convex. Maybe you meant to add them? How did you formulate the problem for cvxopt?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Their product is also convex I think. In CVXOPT, I had to calculate its gradient, hessian and after assigning them, it worked.

Comment: It may not be possible to formulate your problem as a DCP, the set of DCPs is a strict subset of convex programs. Thus you may have to use a CP solver like cvxopt.

Comment: Unfortunately CVXOPT works only for 64bit Windows not 32bit, so it was the issue to consider cvxpy.

Comment: @Jimmy Hi, did you find out what is the problem with CVXPY for your case? can you show how you handle the issue with CVXOPT? Thanks